# How can I have an association fetch an existing record?

Tags: factory-bot

I'd like to write a factory for a blog post, that doesn't create a new user record for every post, but rather pick a random user from those that already exist. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could randomly order your table, take a record and assign it to your Post. Bear in mind that there is definitely a cleaner way to do this, but here's one that works, obviously assuming your users are already in your test database.

```rb
user = User.order("RANDOM()").take #PostgreSQL
user = User.order("RAND()").take #MySQL
post = create(:post, user: user)
```